# C# Windows form graphics not displaying on remote desktop

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

I have developed a program that displays a grid, over my 2 screens (I explained why at the bottom of this message). If I have a remote desktop up, the grid is not displayed over the remote desktop window.

In the image below, it shows my grid over 2 screens (Google + Bing)
[image]

If 1 of the screens includes a remote desktop, then the grid is not displayed over that window.

I have written the project in visual studio 2019. It's a Windows form project and uses the graphics object.

Briefly why? Owing to a disability, I use my computers by speech recognition (Dragon Professional Individual 15). Dragon's mouse grid only works on one screen so I decided to develop my own!

Thanks

The smallest program that I have been able to create is a Windows form project, using visual studio 2019, with the following paint event:-

```
private void minimalexample_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics graphics;
            graphics = this.CreateGraphics();

            Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(100, 100, 500, 500);
            Pen redPen = new Pen(Color.Red, 1);
            graphics.DrawRectangle(redPen, rectangle);


        }
```

On the form, I set the transparency key, to the same as the background colour and removed form elements, such as the title bar et cetera.

The difficult part to reproduce is the fact that I am launching the application using a Dragon macro, which uses Shellexecute.
This can be slightly difficult

Comment: How do you display the grid? Desktop painting? Please refer to [mcve].

Comment: I have added the main part of my code to the bottom of my original question.

Comment: Remote desktop and your app might be fighting over who gets to be on top. Imagine both having topmost set to true. Try using the remote desktop app as windoed and see if that changes anything

Comment: You should create a window, don't you think?  something like this:  https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19213/An-Alpha-Channel-Composited-Windows-Form-with-Desi